# VirtualBox drag & drop from host to guest not working

Tags: drag-and-drop, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am using Windows 10 as my host and Ubuntu 14.04.3 Linux as the guest OS for my VirtualBox VMs.

Even after installing 'Guest Additions' on my VM and setting the 'Drag and Drop' to 'Bidirectional',  I am not able to drag files/folders from the host machine (Windows) to the guest (Linux).

The opposite i.e. dragging and dropping from guest to host is working fine as expected.

What could be the issue? Is it a bug in VirtualBox?

Comment: The drag & drop function is really buggy since the beginning, and It does not look like if it will be fixed soon. Sometimes rebooting the virtual machine helps

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the issue by just adding the user to the vboxsf group, using the next command in the Guest OS (Ubuntu). After restarting the Guest OS this feature started to work normally.

```
sudo adduser $USER vboxsf
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the Virtualbox Guest Additions istalled.

Go to **"Devices->Install Guest Additions"**

Reboot the system and check if it's working.

If it's not working yet, you can check it in newer versions of VirtualBox by searching for `/media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` in your Linux VM.

Then run "`sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`"

Answer (score 0):

In my case even after activating bidirectional and installing 'guest additions' it I was not able to move files either ways.

Interestingly I had always a pop up stating the following.
"You have the autocapture keyboard turned on. bla bla ..."
It basically asked me to press "hostkey" to uncapture the keyboard so that I can switch to windows tabs whenever I want.

and interestingly after pressing "host key" in my case it was German keyboard "STRG-Rechts", or in english "ctrl-right", I was able to move the items bidirectional.

Another option is to simply disable the "Autocapture Keyboard" option!
This way you do not have to deal with pressing "Host-key" every time you want to switch tabs or transfer data between the Guest OS and Host OS or Vice versa.

I spent hours before figuring out this and did not read this info in any answers I found. I should have paid more attention to the notification in the first place.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

you need to activate WaylandEnable=false.

1. Open a terminal.
2. Run the command: **sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf**. Look for the line that contains **# WaylandEnable=false**.
3. Remove the # symbol at the beginning of the line.
4. restart the GDM service by running the command: **sudo
   systemctl restart gdm3**.